# Cardinality of sets and the empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A math logic book gives a puzzling solution to this problem.

Let set $A = \{a, b\}$ . Determine the power set P(A). Determine $|A|$ and $|P(A)|$ .

Solution: $P(A) = \{\emptyset, {a}, {b}, \{a, b\}\}$ . So $|A| = 2, |P(A)| = 4$.

The empty set is a subset of every set. But here it's true only for $P(A)$ , but not for $A$ . Why?

If I explicitly include the empty set as one of the element of $A$ will it increase the cardinality of $A$ ?

Comment: You are mixing $\in$ (to be an element of) with $\subseteq$ (to be a subset of$.

Comment: As you said,  the empty set is subset of A not an element of A..... So nothing happens to the cardinallity of A...

Comment: $\emptyset \subseteq A$ for every set $A$ : the *empty* set is a **subset** of every set. Thus, $\emptyset \in \mathcal P(A)$, because the *power set* is the set of **all** subsets.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: *Cardinality* is relative to the number of elements... not of subsets.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA. Thank you very much. Your second comment is super helpful and It answers my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the empty set is a subset of every set. However, it is not an *element* of each set. That's a different thing.

$\varnothing\notin A$, but $\varnothing\subseteq A$, which makes $\varnothing\in P(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand the reason why the empty set is a subset of every set?
For a set $A$ to be a subset of $B$, i.e. $A\subset B$, it means that for every $x \in A$, $x\in B$. Since the empty set contains no elements, this is a vacuously true statement. (Any time you have an "if..., then..." statement, if the hypothesis is false, the implication is vacuously true.) That is why the empty set is a subset of any set. So, there is no reason to include the empty set in your set $A$.